# I want to build 2 copies of decoder containing same FC layers with different droupout but I want them to share weights. How can this be done?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to build 2 copies of decoder of a model with different dropouts but these layers should share the weights, how can this be achieved with keras ?

I know how to share a layer with keras API (https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#shared-layers) but I want 2 set of layers, as I want to keep different dropouts but they should have common weights.

I want to achieve this architecture.

```
       Conv
       Pool
droupout1 droupout2
  FC1       FC2
softmax1  softmax2
        out
```

Comment: So they idea is that FC1 and FC2 share weights?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to share FC layers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy with the Keras Functional API, I assume you want to share weights between FC1 and FC2:

```
pool_out = SomePoolingLayer()(input_tensor)
shared_fc = Dense(neurons, activation='softmax')
drop1 = Dropout(0.5)(pool_out)
drop2 = Droput(0.5)(pool_out)

fc1 = shared_fc(drop1)
fc2 = shared_fc(drop2)

out = somehow_merge()([fc1, fc2])
```

`somehow_merge` can be any functional merge function like concatenate or average.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I wanted to implement.